# Laravel 5.4 shows diffrent time in xampp and laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, date, xampp

Okay am confessing that am having php 5.4 installed, and laravel 5.4 in my code army.Executing same piece of code in laravel project and outside laravel project (ie: simple xampp project) produces very diffrent results.

## Here is what i tried

timezone is set in php.ini

installed latest version of laravel, 5.4

googling since 24 hours, without any luck

### Test.php (localhost/test/test.php)

```
    <?php 
    ini_set('date.timezone', 'Asia/Kolkata');
    echo date("Y/m/d h:i:s");
    //prints  2017/03/14 07:40:18 
    ?>
```

### Test.blade.php  (localhost/blog/public/test)

```
@extends('layout')

    @section('content')

     <?php 
        ini_set('date.timezone', 'Asia/Kolkata');
        echo date("Y/m/d h:i:s");
        //prints  2017/03/14 01:36:52   
        ?>
    @endsection
```

Okay i reckon this one is stupid problem, or am being stupid enough, looking forward.

Comment: In Laravel - Check app/config/app.php and there the *timezone*, if there is the same timezone

Comment: its  'timezone' => 'UTC', in app.php

Comment: set it to 'Asia/Kolkata'

Comment: its UTC, i want something like UTC +5:30

Comment: set it to 'Asia/Kolkata'